# how to add RelativeLayout after AppbarLayout in CoordinateLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `CoordinateLayout`, in that `AppBarLayout` and below `ScrollView` , `AppbarLayout` and `ScrollView` are overlap to each other. how to set ScrollView below to AppBarLayout. let me know thnks

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_blue"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:scrollbars="none">

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_verysmall"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Add like this way

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:scrollbars="none">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_verysmall"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

put your `ScrollView` Inside the `RelativeLayout`. and also add your `Activity or layout` context in `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: thnks its very help full

Answer (score 1):

add following property in your scroll

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```